# how to use $where in mongoDB javascript

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to get a mongoDB document using close $where but the function return the first document in my database:

```
 scanCode: function (scannedcode) {
    try {

        let carItem = Cars.findOne({ $where: function () { return this.codeBarre == 'TOYOTA CAMRY      MC/ 2007CHASSIS/    509740' } });

        console.log(carItem)
        return carItem;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
```

Comment: You can also try `Cars.findOne({ codeBarre: 'TOYOTA CAMRY MC/ 2007CHASSIS/ 509740' });`  or `Cars.find({ codeBarre: 'TOYOTA CAMRY MC/ 2007CHASSIS/ 509740' }).fetch();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

```
scanCode: function (scannedcode) {
try {

    let carItem = Cars.findOne({ $where: "this.codeBarre == 'TOYOTA CAMRY      MC/ 2007CHASSIS/    509740'" });

    console.log(carItem)
    return carItem;
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
}
```

Comment: @sana so im guessing the logical expression your using is is wrong

Comment: i don't think so :/

Comment: can you explain your goal out of this query ?@sana

Comment: `Cars.findOne({ $where: "this.codeBarre == 'TOYOTA CAMRY      MC/ 2007CHASSIS/    509740' "});` have you tried this method

Comment: how can i pass 'scannedcode' as un args insted of 'TOYOTA CAMRY MC/ 2007CHASSIS/ 509740' ??

Comment: you could use string interpolation 
`"this.codeBarre == '${scannedcode}'"`
or
`let expression = "this.codeBarre == '"+scannedcode+ "' " ; and then use the variable with $where`

Comment: let query = "this.codeBarre.replace(/[/:\s]/g, '') == '" + scannedcode.replace(/[/:\s]/g, '') + "' "  this query gives me undefined

Comment: let query = "this.codeBarre == '" + scannedcode.replace(/[/:\s]/g, '') + "' "
try this

Comment: the problem that i need to remove all white spaces from the value of (this.codeBarre) also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136738/discussion-between-avindu-hewa-and-sana).